# 404 error after deploying react js app on iis

Tags: reactjs, deployment, http-status-code-404

I got error HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found after deploying react js app on IIS on the server.
I created web config and copy configurations but it did not work. even I create an app without long code just with route and simple menu and did all things, again did not work. please Help

here is my App.js

```
import Menu from "./components/Menu";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import About from "./components/About";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Menu />

    <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
     </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

here is my web config file content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configurati
```

I created a website in IIs after creating an application pool with net CLR version: No Managed code
then copy build folder of react app in it.

Comment: Are you using v6 of `react-router-dom`?

Comment: yes I am using react-router-dom

Comment: It was solved with running gpupdate on windows server

Comment: @Nasrin it would be great if you would actually post an answer